# Find out which gems require native c extensions from a Gemfile?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby, bundler, torquebox

I just recently started shifting attention towards deploying Ruby apps atop `TorqueBox` which of course is built atop Jruby.  Hitherto I have been basically performing a `bundle install` and then tackling each gem along the way to jrubydom, but I've hit a couple gems that have taken me some considerable time to resolve due to needing to reimplement large portions of them.

Is there a way to invoke bundler or rubygems to run through all gems and their deps to test if they require native c extensions and then return such a list?  It sure would be nice to tackle some of the more minor items or even to know if it is worthwhile to tackle a project in terms of moving it to jruby.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [JRuby Lint](https://github.com/jruby/jruby-lint) for that. It will will check for some gems requiring C extension and even list alternative (based on [this list](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/C-Extension-Alternatives)).

Answer (score 12):

Based on the fact that gems with native extensions usually have an /ext directory, I made a simple oneliner that finds these gems:

```
puts `bundle show --paths`.split("\n").select{|dep| File.directory?("#{dep}/ext") }.map{|dep| dep.split('/').last }.join(', ')
```

You can do this on the command line with this command:

```
$ bundle show --paths | ruby -e "STDIN.each_line {|dep| puts dep.split('/').last if File.directory?(File.join(dep.chomp, 'ext')) }"
```